# Simultaneous setIntervals - only first one running

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, setinterval

I'm designing a web page that has moving clouds in the background. My code uses jQuery and looks like this.

```
browserWidth = 0;
browserHeight = 0;
clouds = 4; 
cloudSpeed = 50;

$(function() {  
    browserWidth = $(window).width();
    browserHeight =  $(window).height();

    for(i = 0; i < clouds; i++) {
        createCloud(cloudSpeed);
    }
});

function moveCloud(cloud) {
    offset = cloud.offset();
    posX = offset.left;
    posX--;

    if(posX < -250) {
        posX = browserWidth;
    }

    cloud.offset({
        left: posX
    });
}

function createCloud(speed) {
    posY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (browserHeight / 2.5));
    posX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (browserWidth - 255));

    cloud = $("<div></div>").addClass("cloud").appendTo("body").offset({
        top: posY,
        left: posX
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        moveCloud(cloud);
    }, speed);
}
```

Basically it uses `createCloud` function to create fours clouds (divs with background image) which initializes the div and sets an interval using `setInterval`. In the interval function I call function `moveCloud` that moves the div one pixel left. See the code above.

My problem is that it moves only one of the divs. I've read that it should be okay to use multiple intervals simultaneously.

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Also Try `someArr[someArr.length] = setInterval...` Where someArr=[] in global scope

Comment: You should really have a look at animate method

Comment: @roasted I'm aware of animate in jQuery but it's not ideal for this case. With animate you need to specify a time. I could do some tricks though but this seems a bit easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you have only one, global, `cloud`.

Add `var` in front of the declaration :

```
var cloud = $("<div></div>").addClass("cloud").appendTo("body").offset({
```

When you don't use the [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) keyword, you make the variable global.

Comment: Great and extremely fast! Ten minutes and I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't declared `cloud` as a local variable, but in the global context. For more information, see this: http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/global_local_variables_scope_javascript.php3

Answer (score 1):

First of all your question is awsome, secondly this is not an answer to your question as much as it is tweaking to your animation.
i added different layers of opacity to the clouds, increasing interval to the animation speed to make it more realistic (closer clouds move fasted than far ones) and generated random sizes for the clouds, here's the code (pure javascript):

```
var clouds = 4,
    cloudSpeed = 20,
    browserWidth = window.innerWidth,
    browserHeight = window.innerHeight,
    int = 5;

for (i = 0; i < clouds; i++) {
    createCloud(cloudSpeed, i, int);
}


function moveCloud(cloud) {
    var posX = (cloud.offsetLeft < -250) ? browserWidth : cloud.offsetLeft;
    posX--;
    cloud.style.left = posX + "px";
}

function createCloud(speed, index, interval) {
    var posY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (browserHeight / 2.5)),
        posX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (browserWidth - 255)),
        cloud = document.createElement('div'),
        height = h + Math.floor(Math.random() * 40),
        width = w + Math.floor(Math.random() * 40);
    cloud.className = "cloud";
    cloud.innerHTML = svg(width, height);//added svg scalable background, see the demo
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(cloud);
    cloud.style.left = posX + "px";
    cloud.style.top = posY + "px";
    cloud.style.opacity = 1 - (index / 10);
    cloud.style.zIndex = (clouds - index) * 100;
    setInterval(function () {
        moveCloud(cloud);
    }, speed + (interval * index));
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/u8zVm/)

Comment: Very nice looking, thanks for that. I believe I adapt something to my version too :)